# Saving single sheet from workbook with defined destination and date stamp in file name name

Tags: excel, vba

I have almost no VBA experience but I have cobbled the below code together.  I am looking to save a specific sheet from the an excel workbook in a particular file location with a unique file name(date stamp would work fine).

I am able to save off the individual sheet in the correct file type but I am having issues with the following:

The file is not saving to the correct folder.  It is saving on my desk top, not the folder labeled "test files" on my desktop

I am unsure how to add a date stamp to the file name.  The code is currently naming the file "test file".  With the current code I was expecting the file to be name "COLLATERALUPLOAD"

```
Sub SaveCollateralUpload()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("COPY TO FOR UPLOAD").Copy   

Sheets("COPY TO FOR UPLOAD").SaveAs "C:\Desktop\test files\COLLATERALUPLOAD.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Any and all help would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: You're attempting to pull a single sheet to a new workbook?  Would you not want `.Move` rather than `.Copy`?  Additinoally, you would want to save a workbook, not just a sheet, so that could be where you're having issues with your saveas.

Comment: The Copy approach is the correct one. Using Copy without a destination file specified copies the sheet to a new workbook. The newly created workbook is the Active Workbook. Since you know the location you want is a specific folder on your desktop all you need to do is SaveAs and specify the full path with the desired filename as the last part of the full path. Also, using SaveAs on the original workbook will save the entire workbook with a new name with ALL worksheets, not just the single desired sheet.

Comment: @SmileyFtW my mistake on my previous (now deleted) comment - you are right. OP - as far as the datestamp is concerned, just concatenate it into the filename, e.g. `"....COLLATERALUPLOAD " & Format$(Date, "ddmmyyy") & ".xls"`.

Comment: `format(now,"dd_mm_yyyy_hhnnss")` play around with the formatting

Comment: Where exactly would the formatting prompt go?  I was able to sort out the file destination issue, but when I follow the above comment (e.g. "....COLLATERALUPLOAD " & Format$(Date, "ddmmyyy") & ".xls") I run into an sytax error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? As an approach, use the Macro Recorder to generate it.